# Read something in the same print line

Tags: java

I am beginner in `JAVA` programming and I was wondering about 
how can I read a number (or character) in same line that I've print a question

**Example:**

```
 (number to be imputed) : (number to be imputed) : (number to be imputed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print` method, it will not change the line and you can enter the number in the same line

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("enter an number : ");
    input.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does the code below can help?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(s.nextLine());
s.close();
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, some explanation would help.